# Create instance of foreign key object every time parent object is created

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I want to create a Cart object that is linked to the User model in my database. Every time I create a User, I want a linked Cart to be created (in the database).
Any suggestions? I tried linking it to the User id but no joy.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

# Create your models here.


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    img = models.FileField()
    created = models.DateField()
    num_stars = models.IntegerField()


class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,to_field='id', null=True)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_update = models.DateTimeField()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put receiver to handle creation of cart when user is created

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone
class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,to_field='id', null=True)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True,blank=True)
    last_update = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_cart(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Cart.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
```

Comment: Do I put this function in my cart model?

Comment: ValueError: The database backend does not accept 0 as a value for AutoField.

Comment: you need to add content and last_update  as they are not null fields

Comment: or just make null=True for both content and last_update

Comment: when I try create a user, django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'content' cannot be null")

Comment: I changed the content to null=True

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189569/discussion-between-pavan-kumar-t-s-and-adam-howard).

Comment: You got me going in the right direction, it is not working but I am happy with your answer

Comment: here to help chat if problem still persist